# Testing a software bridge application using virtualization

Tags: networking, virtualization

Good evening,

I am stuck at a certain point of development.. As a part of a Routing/Switching course, we have to program a two port software switch/bridge.. But the main problem for me is testing it.. I dont have multiple network cards in my laptop, and i have only one computer. i need to simulate a topology like this:

[image]

However, i dont know how to do it.. i have a Windows XP installed as two Virtualbox machines.. But i dont know how to set it up to make it work.. Neither network option was sufficient(NAT, bridge, host only...)

Can you please help me?

I thank you in advance for all your advice.

Robert

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you split your single network port to multiple subinterfaces like eth0:1 eth0:2 etc. You can run your switching program on these subinterfaces. You can work on the subinterfaces the same way you work with regular interfaces, though these subinterfaces are bydefault attached to the parent interface.